# Flutter Sending Image via Mailer

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to find a solution for my code. I'm trying to send mail with image attachment but I couldn't figured out how to do. I searched nearly all topics in this website but none of it helped me.

Without using attachment, I'm able to send email but when I use attachment and trying to send my image, nothing happens. I hid private information from the code.

```
File newImage;

uploadImage() async {
final _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
final _picker = ImagePicker();
PickedFile image;

  image = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  var file = File(image.path);
  String filName = basename(file.path);
  // Upload to Firebase
  var snapshot = await _storage.ref().child(filName).putFile(file).onComplete;

  var downloadURL = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

  setState(() {
    imageUrl = downloadURL;
    newImage = image; // PickedFile can't be assigned to variable type File
  });
```

}

```
main(message) async{
var options = new SmtpOptions()
  // Hidden
var transport = new SmtpTransport(options);

var envelope = new Envelope()
  ..from = 'example@mail.com'
  ..fromName = 'example'
  ..recipients = ['example2@mail.com']
  ..subject = 'example'
  ..attachments.add(new Attachment(file: new File(newImage))) // File can't be assigned to parameter type 'String'
  ..text = "$message";

transport.send(envelope)
    .then((_) => print('email sent!'))
    .catchError((e) => print('Error: $e'));
```

}

Comment: When you tryed send mail with attachments does in console is display error `Error: ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code instead:

```
..attachments.add(new Attachment(file: new File(newImage.path)))
```